# Java compare 2 lists, see if one contains any item from the other

Tags: java, list

Say i have two lists.

List1: John,Derek,Oliver.
List2: Nico,Yosi,Derek

I need to compare both lists and see if list 1 contains ANYTHING from list2. I have
been trying for days! This is in java.

Comment: If you want something simple- A double for loop where you iterate over all the elements in the first list and for each element, iterate through all the elements in the second and compare.

Comment: Looks at some of the Collection Javadoc.  Have you looked at the `retainAll` method of List - might be a good place to start.

Comment: I used 
      `for (String blv : blacklist) {
       if(className.toString().contains(blv.toString())){
        noneFound = false;
        break;
       }else{
        noneFound = true;
       }
      }` Nothing worked

Answer (score 4):

The [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method should do the trick:

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
if (list1.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println ("list1 contains no elements from list2");
}
```

Edit:
Note that this will modify `list1`. If you don't want to change `list1`, you could use a temporary object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`disjoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) method

```
boolean nothingInCommon = Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);
```

Comment: It looks like a good way to go, but i tried it and it requires strings, meanwhile my lists are List<String> and i tried using .toString()